# C drive partition cannot be extended and System labelled partition cannot be formatted

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

[image: My PC's Partitions]

I would like to extend my partition to cover the system labelled partition and an unallocated partition all lying on the right of the C drive respectively. The option to extend the C partition is Grayed out. I think the System labelled partition is restricting me (Note: nothing important is in the System labelled partition). How can format the system labelled partition so I can extend the C drive. Thank you.

Comment: You have to move the System partition to the end of the disk first.

Comment: Why do you say "System" partition contains nothing important? That is normally where Windows puts its essential boot files (BootMgr, Boot Configuration Data store, etc.).

Comment: If you were to delete the system partition your asking about Windows would immediately stop booting